# Receive "detail": "not found" for detail view with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an api using django rest framework. I need one view to list all items in the datatable and another view that outputs the data for an individual person based on their id.

The list view works at 'api/bios/'. However, I receive the following error when adding an id to the url:

HTTP 404 Not Found
  Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
  Content-Type: application/json
  Vary: Accept

{
      "detail": "Not found."
  }

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import generics, mixins
from api.models import Playerbios
from api.serializers import USASerializer

class USAListView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'trackmanid'
    serializer_class = USASerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Playerbios.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)


class USAView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'trackmanid'
    serializer_class = USASerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Playerbios.objects.all()
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import Playerbios

class USASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Playerbios
        fields = '__all__'
        lookup_field = 'trackmanid'
```

**main/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from api.views import USAView, USAListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/bios/', include('api.urls')),
    path('api/bios/<trackmanid>/', include('api.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('webapp.urls')),

]
```

**api/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import USAView, USAListView

urlpatterns = [
    url('(?P<trackmanid>)/', USAView.as_view(), name='usa-rud-view'),
    url('', USAListView.as_view(), name='usa-list-view'),
]
```

Comment: add ^ (caret sign) in start and $(dollar sign) in the end of url's regex in api/urls.py  Then your url's should be : url('^(?P<trackmanid>)/$', USAView.as_view(), name='usa-rud-view'), url('^$', USAListView.as_view(), name='usa-list-view'),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using `Viewsets` for this API? DRF has a powerful `ViewSet` that performs all of these functions with just minimal configuration. For example, this can be re-written as:

**views.py**

```
class USAViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Playerbios.objects.all()
    serializer_class = USASerializer
    lookup_field = 'trackmanid'
```

**main urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/bios/', include('api.urls')),
    ...    
]
```

**api/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
)
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'coupon', USAViewset)
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

DRF will do the rest!
Read more here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: Works perfect! And much simpler than what I had prior

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to remove this line from your main urls.py file

```
path('api/bios/<trackmanid>/', include('api.urls'))
```

Also change your `api/urls.py` to include the regex. The format is `?P<name>[regex]`. Assuming `trackmanid` is an integer, you need to include a `\d+` regex next to it.

```
url('(?P<trackmanid>\d+)/', USAView.as_view(), name='usa-rud-view'),
```

Comment: I actually tried that before but I still would receive the same error. However, given your explanation, I will keep it removed.

Comment: Both the changes should do the trick. Also, put a pdb on both views to debug who is serving your request if anyone at all. If you have template debug on, please share the error stack trace here for more help.